# Symfony ; the service "pathauto.verbose_messenger" has a dependency on a non-existent service "messenger"

Tags: symfony, drupal, drupal-8

My Drupal 8 suddenly stopped working it is giving me this error:

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The service "pathauto.verbose_messenger" has a dependency on a non-existent service "messenger". in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(Array) (Line: 42)
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processDefinition(Object) (Line: 36)
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->process(Object) (Line: 120)
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object) (Line: 573)
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() (Line: 1314)
>   Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->compileContainer() (Line: 891)
>   Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 467)
>   Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 663)
>   Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)`

It seems Symfony can not find the service `messenger`  Does anyone has suggestions where is the problem and what is missing? Thanks!

VerboseMessenger.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\pathauto;

use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface as CoreMessengerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/**
 * Provides a verbose messenger.
 */
class VerboseMessenger implements MessengerInterface {

  /**
   * The verbose flag.
   *
   * @var bool
   */
  protected $isVerbose;

  /**
   * The config factory.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface
   */
  protected $configFactory;

  /**
   * The current user account.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface
   */
  protected $account;

  /**
   * The messenger service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface
   */
  protected $messenger;

  /**
   * Creates a verbose messenger.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory
   *   The config factory.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account
   *   The current user account.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface $messenger
   *   The messenger service.
   */
  public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory, AccountInterface $account, CoreMessengerInterface $messenger) {
    $this->configFactory = $config_factory;
    $this->account = $account;
    $this->messenger = $messenger;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function addMessage($message, $op = NULL) {

    if (!isset($this->isVerbose)) {
      $config = $this->configFactory->get('pathauto.settings');
      $this->isVerbose = $config->get('verbose') && $this->account->hasPermission('notify of path changes');
    }

    if (!$this->isVerbose || (isset($op) && in_array($op, array('bulkupdate', 'return')))) {
      return FALSE;
    }

    if ($message) {
      $this->messenger->addMessage($message);
    }

    return TRUE;
  }

}
```

services.yml

```
services:
  pathauto.generator:
    class: Drupal\pathauto\PathautoGenerator
    arguments: ['@config.factory', '@module_handler', '@token', '@pathauto.alias_cleaner', '@pathauto.alias_storage_helper', '@pathauto.alias_uniquifier', '@pathauto.verbose_messenger', '@string_translation', '@token.entity_mapper', '@entity_type.manager']
  pathauto.alias_cleaner:
    class: Drupal\pathauto\AliasCleaner
    arguments: ['@config.factory', '@pathauto.alias_storage_helper', '@language_manager', '@cache.discovery', '@transliteration', '@module_handler']
  pathauto.alias_storage_helper:
    class: Drupal\pathauto\AliasStorageHelper
    arguments: ['@config.factory', '@path.alias_storage', '@database','@pathauto.verbose_messenger', '@string_translation']
    tags:
      - { name: backend_overridable }
  pathauto.alias_uniquifier:
    class: Drupal\pathauto\AliasUniquifier
    arguments: ['@config.factory', '@pathauto.alias_storage_helper','@module_handler', '@router.route_provider', '@path.alias_manager']
  pathauto.verbose_messenger:
    class: Drupal\pathauto\VerboseMessenger
    arguments: ['@config.factory', '@current_user', '@messenger']
  plugin.manager.alias_type:
    class: Drupal\pathauto\AliasTypeManager
    parent: default_plugin_manager
  pathauto.settings_cache_tag:
    class: Drupal\pathauto\EventSubscriber\PathautoSettingsCacheTag
    arguments: ['@entity_field.manager', '@plugin.manager.alias_type']
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Comment: It's never "suddenly" :D. Did you before this happened: 1) Change your environment? 2) Change your PHP version? 3) composer update?

Comment: i dont know really :D

Comment: Could you please give some more details on your Drupal setup? The `messenger` service is only available for core > `8.5.x`